# How to return to the different sections of the menu created

Tags: linux, bash, nmap

I need return value "response1" when the user fail the answers, same case for "response2". My idea is If they get the answer right, let them continue the cycle, if not, return to the previous question. I don't really understand if a return can be done, as it doesn't work for me and I don't know if I can do this with "case".

```
function validate_ip()
{
local  ip=$insertIP
local  stat=1
if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]];
then
OIFS=$IFS
IFS='.'
ip=($ip)
IFS=$OIFS
[[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255  && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]] 
stat=$?
fi
return $stat
}

echo "";
echo -n "Insert IP: ";
read -r insertIP;
echo $ip
if validate_ip insertIP;
then echo "Running Nmap";
    response1=$(echo "return here!!!");
    echo "Which is the simpliest way to launch Nmap?: "
    read -t 30 -r nmap;
    minusculas=$(echo "$nmap" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
        case $minusculas in
        nmap)
                echo "Correct!!!"
                 response2=$(echo "return here2!!!");
                 echo "Which option is use for UDP scan"
                    read -t 30 -r nmap2;
                    case $nmap2 in
                    -sU)
                        echo "Correct!!!"
                    ;;
                    *)
                        echo "Play again!!!"
                        return "$response2"
                    ;;
                    esac
        ;;
        *)
                echo "Play again!!!"
                return "$response1"
        ;;
        esac

#echo $insertIP
else
echo "This is not a IP";
fi
```

Comment: I forgot to assign the variable to response 1 ,changed the code.. Thanks!!!

Comment: Lots of problems in this code. Use https://www.shellcheck.net to help you fix the syntax errors. The most problematic: `response1=echo "return here!!!;` is missing the closing quote. That breaks the rest of the code. But you're also missing the command substitution syntax. But you don't need to capture the output of echoing a string: just store the string in the array.

Comment: @gleenjackman the code is already fixed, but I don't understand how to do what I'm looking for, I don't have very advanced knowledge in bash or in programming.

Comment: Bash functions can only return numbers (exit/status codes) but response1 is a string. Either just print it or store it in a global variable. The big question is: Where do you want to send that string?  Your case statement isn't even inside a function.

Comment: "the code is already fixed" -- then update your question so we can focus on the real problem.